# Read simple CSV via Apify

Tags: apify

I want to create a daily task in Apify that reads this very simple csv: https://api.alternative.me/fng/?format=csv and parse the data to Google Sheets. I'm a Apify beginner and wonder how this can be done with a few lines of code.

Best from Berlin

Answer (score 1):

You can write an [actor](https://docs.apify.com/actor) on Apify platform, which is a JavaScript code. You can then [scheduler](https://docs.apify.com/scheduler) this code to run daily/monthly or whenever you want to. You can even run it manually from UI.

In the javascript code you will need to request CSV from the URL the first, I recommend to use got and csv-parse packages for that. After that, you will need to parse CSV and import the parsed data to google sheet. You can use [google sheets Import & Export](https://apify.com/lukaskrivka/google-sheets), which is ready to use solution for Apify actors.

There is a simple code, which can help you to start building an actor.

```
const Apify = require('apify');
const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync');
const got = require('got');

Apify.main(async () => {
    const { body: csv } = await got('http://example.com/my.csv');

    const records = parse(csv, {
        columns: true,
        skip_empty_lines: true
    });


    const updates = [];
    records.forEach((record) => {
        // Do something with the record
        updates.push(record);
    });

    await Apify.call('lukaskrivka/google-sheets', {
        spreadsheetId: 'your_spreadsheetId',
        mode: 'append',
        rawData: updates,
    })
});
```